# disable default sorting in grouping column dx-data-grid devextreme angular

Tags: angular, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I don't want to use default sorting feature of DevExtreme, my datasource is already sorted, when i make my column as group column using group index DevExtreme DataGrid sort it automatically. I want to stop DevExtreme DataGrid default sorting. Kindly suggest solution.

here is my dx-data-grid

```
<dx-data-grid 
    id="masterGrid"
    [dataSource]="globalLimit"
    [showBorders]="true"
    [allowColumnReordering]="true"
    [twoWayBindingEnabled]="true"
    [allowColumnResizing]="true">

   <dxo-sorting mode="none"></dxo-sorting>
     <dxi-column dataField="groupName"  [allowSorting]="false"  [autoExpandGroup]="true"  [groupIndex]="0" >  </dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="d1"  > </dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="d2"  ></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="d3" ></dxi-column>
</dx-data-grid>
```

Here is my data in json from server in  sorted order

```
 { "groupName":"test", 
  "d1":23900,  
  "d2":2200, 
  "d3":1452 
},
{ 
 "groupName":"test", 
  "d1":2562,  
  "d2":20000, 
  "d3":252150 
},
{ 
 "groupName":"test", 
  "d1":23215,  
  "d2":6256, 
  "d3":21121 
},{ 
 "groupName":"abc", 
  "d1":515,  
  "d2":2151, 
  "d3":5151 
},
 { 
 "groupName":"abc", 
  "d1":5000,  
  "d2":21510, 
  "d3":51010
}
  }
```

Here is screenshot of my grid 
[image: grouping grid screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to Your table. Look on documentation to find more remote options.

```
<dxo-remote-operations [sorting]="true"></dxo-remote-operations>
```